# Can Pristine be used for buttons?

Tags: html, angularjs

in which I'm getting the values from a Modal. I'm able to save the selected values. Also, I need to update the values. I'm using Pristine in the following code through which I'm able to update the fields which have input type text. But I'm not able to update the values in button fields. I know that Pristine cannot handle button fields. Is there any other way to do this?

Code in controller:

```
 $scope.cpform = {
                                    summary: r_header.summary,
                                    severity:r_header.severity,
                                    occurence:r_header.occurence,
                                    detection:r_header.detection,
                                    risk_score: r_header.risk_score,
                                    nocpz: nocpz_checked,
                                    route: r_header.route,
                                    layers: r_header.layers,
                                    comments: r_header.comments,
                                    risks: risk_id_list,


                                };

            }



            $scope.updateReview = function (cpform, formname) {
                $scope.uprev_submit_disabled = true;
                var updated_field_list = [];


                if (r_header.revSeverity[0] != null) {
                    angular.forEach($scope.cpform, function(value, key) {
                        //if(key[0] == '$') return;
                        console.log("Chck", value, key);
                        if (!formname[key].$pristine) {
                            updated_field_list.push(key);
                        }
                        console.log("CPZ", key, formname[key].$pristine)
                     });
                }
```

The fields which need to be saved and updated are in $scope.cpform. In that the button fields are Severity, Occurence, Detection and risk_score. Other fields are text fields(able to update). Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No, you can not use prinstine for the buttons. You can only use it for the input html elements. Eg. <input type="" />

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to update the button values other than pristine?

Comment: Yeah, you can use ng-click to make this happen. Here is a example for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/gdbINDSrs8Q8qqxzVVka?p=preview